# How to parse NSDictionary data from JSONValue

Tags: objective-c, json, twitter, nsdictionary

I have a NSDictionary made up of the daily trend from twitter (made up of JSON). However there is a problem blocking my way. Before I can get to any data, I need to firstly get through the first key named @"trends". That is fine and works perfectly. However to actually get to the trend itself, I need to get through a few dates. What I would like to know is how can I get the trend data without knowing the dates.

At the moment the hierachy of the NSDictionary is:

Dictionary -> key:@"trends" -> Lots of keys named as dates, i.e: 2011-04-30 02:32:34 (this is where I am stuck) -> trend data (what I need to get).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSDictionary *trends = [yourResultFromParsingJSON objectForKey:@"trends"];

[trends enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *trendDate, id trendData, BOOL *stop) {
    // do whatever you want with trendData
}];
```

Comment: First line of code is really helpful for getting a specific key and all data inside it

Answer (score 1):

```
for(NSDictionary* key in responseDict) {
    if ([key isEqual:@"abc"]) {
        NSString *cookieValue = [responseDict objectForKey:@"abc"];
        cookieValue = [cookieValue substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(11, 32)];
    }
}
```